# How to avoid triggering change event when new model is added into collection in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Now I have defined a collection, and bond both add and change event listener, but when a new model is added, the change event will be triggered.

```
collection.bind('add',addMethod);
collection.bind('change',changeMethod);
```

How can I avoid triggering change event?

Comment: You can use pass  `{silent: true }` when adding the model prevent events from triggering.

Comment: Use it like this:
collection.add(model,{silent:true})?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, when you add something to your collection, add silent-option to that function-call. Check [Backbonejs reference](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) for more info.

```
collection.add(someModel, {silent: true});
```